# Intersperse 2D with 3D opengl

Tags: opengl, 2d, 3d

I want to be able to draw 3D objects as well as 2D objects in an openGL environment. Normally, I would draw my 3D stuff, disable the depth buffer and depth mask, then draw my 2D stuff.

However, this creates a hassle. What if I have a single `draw()` function that is supposed to draw 3D and 2D? I would need to separate it, which I really don't want to do. I want to be able to do stuff like `draw3D(...); draw2D(...); draw3D(...);`

So is there a common way of doing this? I can think of a few solutions but would prefer to do it a standard way.

Here's a visual of the problem. My 2D text is interfering with my 3D environment:
[image: ▲▲▲]

Answer (score 1):

It is pretty complicated stuff going on and its not that simple as it
look bcs of the way of opengl buffering system works.The best way to
do it is just draw 3d and then 2d. You might create some kind of
ArrayList which will keep track of all 2d drawing requests. And when 3d is
done you execute them all.

Comment: That's one way I was thinking of doing it, but it seemed really inefficient. I also solved my problem in another way; I translate all 2D values 1 forward on along the Z axis. I don't understand it but that's cool.

Comment: The reason that works is because when you project the 3D scene, everything ends up somewhere between 1 (at the "near" distance) and -1 (at the "far" distance) on the Z-axis.  If you draw your 2D objects at a Z of 1, they will always be on top of anything else.